# Show that the mapping $I : C([a,b]) \to \Bbb{R}$, $I(f) = \int_{a}^{b} f(s) \ ds$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $C([a,b])$ be the norm space of continuous functions $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ with the metric $\|f\|_{\infty}= \max_{s\in[a,b]} |f(s)|$. Show that the mapping $I : C([a,b]) \to \Bbb{R}$ $$I(f) = \int_{a}^{b} f(s) \ ds$$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Letting $f,g \in C([a,b])$ I have that $$|I(f)-I(g)| = |\int_{a}^{b} f(s) \ ds-\int_{a}^{b} g(s) \ ds| = \int_{a}^{b}|f(s)-g(s)| \ ds \leqslant \int_{a}^{b} \max_{s\in [a,b]} |f(s)-g(s)| \ ds$$

but I cannot find any $M$ for the Lipschitz condition, I guess it comes from the integral, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: M = |b-a|. That is just pull max out of integral to get $|I(f)-I(g)| <= |b-a| *||f-g||_{\infty}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you to use a different dummy variable for that $\max$, to avoid a clash of variables under the integral sign:
$$\int_a^b \max_{t \in [a,b]} |f(t)-g(t)| \, ds
$$
And the value of that $\max$ is, of course, a constant independent of $s \in [a,b]$, equal to $\|f\|_\infty$. Perhaps you can finish now?

Comment: Ah I see it seems that $M = (b-a)$. Thanks.